# Simple way to overload compound assignment operator in C#?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, overloading

Does anyone have a very simple example of how to overload the compound assignment operator in C#?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't explicitly overload the compound assignment operators.  You can however overload the main operator and the compiler expands it.

`x += 1` is purely syntactic sugar for `x = x + 1` and the latter is what it will be translated to.  If you overload the `+` operator it will be called.

[MSDN Operator Overloading Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(VS.71).aspx)

```
public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2) 
{
   return new Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary);
}
```

Comment: here is a good article on the subject of overloading operators in C#: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101373&seqNum=15

Comment: I know it can be overloaded in that way, I just want a very simple code example. Anyone?

Comment: 'x += 1 is purely syntactic sugar for x = x + 1' this is not completely correct. See my answer.

Comment: Also this explains the differenec between x+=1 and x=x+1: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/29/compound-assignment-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 4):

According to the C# specification, += is not in the list of overloadable operators. I assume, this is because it is an assignment operator as well, which are not allowed to get overloaded. However, unlike stated in other answers here, 'x += 1' is **not** *the same* as 'x = x + 1'. The C# specification, "7.17.2 Compound assignment" is very clear about that:

```
... the operation is evaluated as x = x op y, except that x is evaluated only once
```

The important part is the last part: x is evaluated only once. So in situations like this:

```
A[B()] = A[B()] + 1;
```

it can (and does) make a difference, how to formulate your statement. But I assume, in most situations, the difference will negligible. (Even if I just came across one, where it is not.)

The answer to the question therefore is: one cannot override the += operator. For situations, where the intention is realizable via simple binary operators, one can override the + operator and archieve a similiar goal.

Answer (score 2):

You can't overload those operators in C#.

Comment: Stephan's post indicates that you can. Of course you can't override it orthogonally from the + operator, but hey, it's technically possible.

Comment: @dss539 - Indirectly, sure. I was just answering his question.

Comment: @dss539 - It's "technically possible"? If anything, "technically possible" is exactly what it is not.

Comment: @Tod You can overload the + operator and thereby change the behavior of the += operator. So yes, it is possible.