# Why cant i overload the += operator in C#? But i still can use it?

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple way to overload compound assignment operator in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869245/simple-way-to-overload-compound-assignment-operator-in-c)

I was playing around with events and thought events are weird. Why couldnt i just implement them in a generic class. So i tried to and found that i CANT OVERLOAD +=. [From the language specs found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)

```
The overloadable unary operators are:    
+   -   !   ~   ++   --   true   false

The overloadable binary operators are:    
+   -   *   /   %   &   |   ^   <<   >>   ==   !=   >   <   >=   <=
```

+= is not listed. Now, before you say theres no reason to overload += i'd like to bring up the fact C# has events which uses the += operator and the fact i tried to implement an event for fun and wanted to use the += operator. Now, i have a feeling someone will say thats why events exist, because it is the only reason. However i want to bring up you can use += with the TimeSpan struct. Go try it, `var ts= new TimeSpan(); ts += ts;` will compile and run.

I looked at TimeSpan definition and i have no idea how it is allowing it. I saw a `public static TimeSpan operator +(TimeSpan t);` which looked suspicious but then i realize its for something like `var name = +ts;` like how you can do `var name = -ts;` for negation.

So my question is, how do i use the += for my struct or class. It appears to be supported i just cant seem to find the documentation on it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Events don't overload the `+=` and `-=` operator. This is just hardcoded in the C# compiler which translates it into the add/remove methods of that event.

You can only overload `+` and `-` which then indirectly overload `+=` and `-=`. If you overload `+` then automatically `x += y` becomes overloaded to `x = x + y`. So for your type you don't need to put in any extra work. Just overload `+` and you'll get `+=` for free. This of course requires the left side argument and the result type being compatible, but that's usually the case.

---

The reason that you can't overload `+=` separately is most likely that it creates strange semantics for reference types. If `+=` modified the existing instance of the left side then the following code would behave strangely:

```
MyClass x=new MyClass();
MyClass y=x;
x+=SomeThing;
y has changed now too
```

On the other hand with `+=` meaning `x = x+y` this code creates a new instance which it assigns to x. And the original instance remains unmodified in y;

---

In C++ on the other hand it is possible to safely specify a separate overload for `+=` because you can overload the assignment and copy-constructor at the same time and use that to get the correct semantics.

Comment: Great answer you explain exactly why += cant be overloaded and gave me reasoning that actually make sense!

Comment: Maybe you know the answer to this as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203093

Comment: Overloading `+=` separately could create strange semantics, but it would also allow a type to perform the read and write-back in thread-safe manner [e.g. `event += someDelegate`; is implemented in thread-safe fashion, and one could code `void myThing.AddTo(ref myThing dest, myThing src);` so as to make `myThing.AddTo(ref someSharedField, someData)` safe, but `someSharedField = someSharedField + someData;` cannot be made intrinsically thread-safe.  Without being able to map `+=` to a method that takes a `ref` parameter, it cannot be used in inherently thread-safe fashion except for events.

Answer (score 1):

> The += operator cannot be overloaded
> directly, but user-defined types can
> overload the + operator.
>
> An expression using the += assignment
> operator, such as Copy
>
> x += y
>
> is equivalent to Copy
>
> x = x + y

[Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`+=` is just a shorthand for addition, then assignment. You can overload the `+` operator, which also makes the `+=` operator work:

This compiles

```
class P 
{
    public static P operator +(P rhs, P lhs) {
        return null;
    }   
}

void Main()
{
    P p = new P();
    p += new P();
}
```

(And, vice versa for `-` and `-=` operators, of course).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation doesn't lie. It's not possible to overload the `+=` operator.

The `+=` operator is just a shortcut for using the `+` operator. An operation like `x += y` is translated into `x = x + y` by the compiler.

So, to change what the `+=` operator does, you have to overload the `+` operator.