# How does operator overloading of true and false work?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

You can overload operator true and false i looked at examples and found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691312%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

I completely dont understand how they work. I know if i write if(obj) and true returns true then the if is executed. It doesnt matter what false returns. However how does false work? in that doc it is suggected that the && operator uses it. I wrote the code below. I dont know how to get && to compile. || gives me a compile error too. How do i get false to be called? and how do i get the && and || to work?

```
        var ts= new MyTimeSpan();// ts += ts;
        if (ts){ Console.WriteLine("Is true"); }
        else { Console.WriteLine("not true"); }
        //Console.WriteLine(ts && ts ? "Y" : "N");

    class MyTimeSpan
    {
        public static MyTimeSpan operator +(MyTimeSpan t, MyTimeSpan t2) { return new MyTimeSpan(); }
        public static bool operator true(MyTimeSpan t) { return true; }
        public static bool operator false(MyTimeSpan t) { return false; }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does it mean for a timespan to be true or false?

Comment: @Mark: I was messing around with the + operator in my last question/example which led me to this and i used the same class. The name is a dummy, i am just learning how the ops work.

Comment: You haven't declared operators for & or | - looking at the documentation link you provided it states you need to declare these operators, they need to return MyTimeSpan objects _and_ you need to declare operators for true and false.  The documentation also explains where true and false operators are used.

Comment: @James: For some reason, i was thinking && as if left and right side is both true and didnt see how the logical and relates to it. Now i see it does a and between the two ops and checks if it is true. Which is weird to me. Cause 1 && 2 is illegal in C# and in C++ it is true as there is no logical AND being applied http://codepad.org/9iCaqzQ2

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The defining property of a short circuiting operator is that it doesn't need to evaluate the right side if the left side already determines the result. For `or` if the left side is `true` the result will be true in any case and it's unnecessary to evaluate the right side. For `and` it's the same except that if the left side is `false` the result will be false.

You need to overload both `|` and `true` to get `||`. And `&` and `false` to get `&&`.

`a||b` corresponds to something like `op_true(a)?a:(a|b)`. So if the true operator returns true it does not need to evaluate the expression of b.

`a&&b` corresponds to something like `op_false(a)?a:(a&b)`. So if the false operator returns true it does not need to evaluate the expression of b.

Overloading the short circuiting operators is useful when creating a custom boolean type, such as nullable bools(See `DBBool`)

Comment: This confused me horribly. I was thinking && as if left and right side is both true and didnt see how the logical and relates to it. Now i see it does a AND between the two values and checks if it is true. Which is weird to me. Cause 1 && 2 is illegal in C# and in C++ it is true as there is no logical AND being applied (1&2==0==false, in this c code it says its true) codepad.org/9iCaqzQ2

Comment: you dont need to answer this one but i made my comment into a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203498/why-does-c-and-operators-work-the-way-they-do

Comment: @acid My answer had a big mistake. Perhaps that confused you.

Answer (score 9):

When overloading the `true` and `false` operators they don't just return `true` and `false`, they are used to determine if a value of your type is considered to be true or false.

If for example a zero value in your class represents false, then a non-zero value represents true:

```
public static bool operator true(MyTimeSpan t) { return t.Value != 0; }
public static bool operator false(MyTimeSpan t) { return t.Value == 0; }
```

As the operators are each others inverse, the compiler doesn't need to use both to determine if a value is true or false. If you write `if(obj)` the compiler will use the `true` operator to determine if the value is true.

Comment: +1. Also see comment i left in my question or the nearly same comment on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203093/how-does-operator-overloading-of-true-and-false-work/5203185#5203185

Comment: you dont need to answer this one but i made my comment into a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203498/why-does-c-and-operators-work-the-way-they-do

Comment: If X is some arbitrary type which overrides those operators but one knows nothing else about it, is there any way to determine whether X is "false" (as opposed to merely not being "true")?

Comment: @supercat: I'm not sure. I tried some different ways to test it, but I haven't found a way to make use of the `false` operator without also overloading the `&` operator.

Comment: @Guffa: It's too bad `if` uses the `true` operator rather than attempting an implicit cast to `bool` or else having a syntax specifically to use the `true` and `false` operators [e.g. `if true (threeStateCOnditional) { codeIfTrue } else if false { codeIfFalse} else { codeIfNeither }`]  The fact that a type supports short-circuited operators doesn't necessarily mean it should be directly usable as a condition.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override & operator for && and | or ||.

Somthing like this: (Just a dummy code)

```
public static MyTimeSpan operator &(MyTimeSpan t, MyTimeSpan s) { return t; }

public static MyTimeSpan operator |(MyTimeSpan t, MyTimeSpan s) { return t; }
```