# Wrong statement double.TryParse out parameter might not be initialized?

Tags: c#, out

If wonder why the compiler does not allow me to write the following:

```
if (someCondition && double.TryParse(astring, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double v))
{
    // CS0165   Use of unassigned local variable 'v'
    // Seems incorrect, evaluating the conditions will never leave the variable unassigned
}
```

While it's perfectly fine to write

```
if (double.TryParse(astring, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double v))
{
    // No compiler warning, the out parameter is always set
}
```

Why does the compiler not allow me to write the first example?

#### update

the input was a string, but was stored in a `dynamic` property.
Damien_The_Unbeliever already pointed out the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541845/bug-with-detection-of-unassigned-local-variables-when-dynamic-variables-affect) which already explains what this means.

Comment: if `someCondition` is false the second part won't be executed at all...

Comment: Is `dynamic` involved anywhere near here? There's a gotcha if the compiler doesn't know whether custom operator true and false might be in play.

Comment: Inside the `if`, `v` is definitely assigned. *Outside* the `if`, it's assigned only if `someCondition` was `true`, which is not definitive.

Comment: Here's the [old question with dynamic in play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541845/bug-with-detection-of-unassigned-local-variables-when-dynamic-variables-affect)

Comment: Use & instead of && to ensure the TryParse() method runs as well.

Comment: My guess is that the variable is being used after the if-statement block as well, which is actually triggering the problem. However, I've only tested this using C# 8 in .NET Core 3, if there's any differences between this and earlier compilers that might also be a factor.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I think you nailed it. The answer is yes....

Comment: Ah, dynamic is used? Then all bets are off.

Comment: A quick test in LinqPad (using bool and string variables) shows no complaints

Comment: Please post a full [mcve], so that we can see all the moving bits involved.