# C# join 2 or more classes together?

Tags: c#

So this might sounds like a n00b question, but I want to take 2 classes and merge them together.

Like so :

```
Ball oneBall = new Ball("red", 20);
Ball anotherBall = new Ball("blue",40);


Ball BigBall = new Ball(oneBall + anotherBall);

BigBall.size() //should say 60 right?
```

I know you would have something like this

```
class Ball{


  public Ball(string Name , int size){}

// But to merge to of them? 

  public Ball(Ball firstBall, Ball secondBall){} //I know the arguments have to be added
{}


}
```

So my question is what is the overload(right?) suppose to look like?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you looking for operator overloading? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587107/c-sharp-operator-overload-for

Comment: `class HairyBall extends Ball implements BigBall` scnr

Comment: @ThiefMaster I like your logic haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want to overload the addition operator for `Ball`, something like:

```
public static Ball operator +(Ball left, Ball right)
{
    return new Ball(left.Name + right.Name, left.Size + right.Size);
}
```

Although making a `Ball` constructor that takes in 2 `Ball`s and adds them is probably more readable, but if you actually want to write `new Ball(ball1 + ball2)` then operator overloading would work. If you did it with a constructor, then your code would look like: `new Ball(ball1, ball2)`

Comment: That's what I was lookin for! I just knew my syntax was off for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can define a constructor overload.

```
public class Ball
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Size { get; private set; }

    public Ball(string name, int size) 
    { 
        this.Name = name;
        this.Size = size;
    }

    // This is called constructor chaining
    public Ball(Ball first, Ball second)
        : this(first.Name + "," + second.Name, first.Size + second.Size)
    { }
}
```

To merge the two balls:

```
Ball bigBall = new Ball(oneBall, anotherBall);
```

Note that you are calling the constructor overload, not the `+` operator.

Comment: Actually, I prefer this way over my answer. +1.

Answer (score 5):

```
public class Ball
{
    public int Size { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Ball(string name , int size)
    {
        Name = name;
        Size = size;
    }

    public Ball(Ball firstBall, Ball secondBall)
    {
        Name = firstBall.Name + ", " + secondBall.Name;
        Size = firstBall.Size + secondBall.Size;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is about right, just pass the two balls as two parameters to the second overload

```
Ball BigBall = new Ball(oneBall , anotherBall);
```

and adjust the overload so it adds the two ball sizes together:

```
public Ball(Ball firstBall, Ball secondBall){} //I know the arguments have to be added
{
    this.size = firstBall.size + secondBall.size;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define the addition operator for your type if it makes sense:

```
public static operator+(Ball rhs, Ball lhs) 
{
    return new Ball(lhs.Size + rhs.Size);
}
```

Only do this if it semantically makes sense to add two instances of `Ball` together.

Comment: You are mixing things. `implicit` and `explicit` are for type conversions. `operator xy` is for operator overloading.