# Conditional logical operator working with =

Tags: c#

I know that the following code will execute both the left and right expressions :

```
bool myBool = true;
myBool &= Foo();
```

Is there any way to write the same way (a kind of `&&=`) a code that will produce :

```
bool myBool = true;
myBool = myBool &&  Foo();
```

Instead of

```
myBool = myBool & Foo();
```

Comment: no, you can't use it in this way

Comment: Be specific in what you mean with "write the same way". Judging on the answer you weren't very clear.

Comment: what's wrong with `myBool = myBool &&  Foo();`?

Comment: nothing, i just would be sure there wasn't another way to write it without writing two times `myBool`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no operator `&&=` in C#. So you can't do this.

For the list of all operators, take a look on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you want `Foo()` be executed, just *swap*:

```
  bool myBool = ...;
  myBool = Foo() && myBool;
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't wan't it to be executed. It is when i use `myBool &= Foo()`

Answer (score 1):

Will this answer your question? (wasn't really clear)

```
bool myBool = true;
myBool = myBool ||  (!myBool && Foo());
```

Only if the `myBool` is `false` then the function will be executed

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned there is no `&&=`-operator thus you can´t overload any. For a list of operators you can overload for any type see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/). For assignement-operators there are no overloads defined at all:

> Assignment operators cannot be overloaded, but +=, for example, is evaluated using +, which can be overloaded.

So your current approach using `myBool &&  Foo();` is the way to go.

As mentioned on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587107/c-sharp-operator-overload-for/6587134#6587134) the IL for `&=` and `&` are equal making the former just syntactic sugar of the latter. So there´d be no real value on creating such an operator as all its use would be to get rid of a few characters.