# Inserting String Into StringBuilder Causes Runtime Error

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, string-concatenation

I am attempting to insert a string into a `StringBuilder` but I get a runtime error:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

My code:

```
Branch curBranch("properties", "");
foreach (string line in fileContents) 
{
    if (isKeyValuePair(line))
       curBranch.Value += line + "\r\n"; // Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
}
```

Implementation of Branch

```
public class Branch {
    private string                      key         = null;
    public StringBuilder                _value      = new StringBuilder(); // MUCH MORE EFFICIENT to append to. If you append to a string in C# you'll be waiting decades LITERALLY
    private Dictionary <string, Branch> children    = new Dictionary <string, Branch>();

    public Branch(string nKey, string nValue) {
        key     = nKey;
        _value.Append(nValue);
    }

    public string Key {
        get { return key; }
    }

    public string Value {
        get 
        { 
            return this._value.ToString(); 
        }   
        set 
        {
            this._value.Append(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are basically appending an entire copy of what you have in the stringbuilder with each call of curBranch.Value += line + "\r\n";  I don't think this is doing what you want it to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line returns the *entire* `StringBuilder` contents:

```
return this._value.ToString();
```

And then you add a string to the end of the entire previous contents:

```
curBranch.Value += line + "\r\n";
```

And append it here:

```
this._value.Append(value);
```

Your `StringBuilder` is going to get huge very quickly, because every time you call the "setter" you're placing a copy of the entire contents into it again.

---

What you might consider instead is exposing the `StringBuilder` via your property:

```
public StringBuilder Value
{
    get { return this._value; }   
}
```

Then just use it like this:

```
curBranch.Value.AppendLine(line);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes that solution would work. I was hoping for a more elegant solution that will allow the `+=` operator. Any ideas how I could maintain using this operator but only concatenate the line (not the whole StringBuilder string and line)?

Comment: @JakeM You can always redefine the "+" operator. This would allow you to do what you want. Here is an example of how to proceed : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fbs5e2h.aspx. However, I do recommend you use the `AppendLine` method as its meaning is not ambiguous and could hardly be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string line in fileContents) 
{
    if (isKeyValuePair(line))
       sb.AppendLine(line); // Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
}
```

Try the above

I also found this explenation for why += isn't there for StringBuilder:

[Why didn't microsoft overload the += operator for stringbuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923816/why-didnt-microsoft-overload-the-operator-for-stringbuilder)