# C# how to know if overload operator+ is a compound assignment (+=)?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I have the following problem:

I can statically overload the operator+ to add some custom objects:

```
public static obj operator+(obj A, obj B)
{
    obj ret = new obj();
    ret.magic = A.magic + B.magic;
    return ret;
}
```

The return is a new object that got *whatever* summed by operator+. Which is perfect.

But when writing…

```
obj A, B;
/* ... */
A += B;
```

This would not increment `A`, it would construct a new `A`. So `A` does not only hold a new value, it is a completely new object, which is not what I want when I write `A += B`.

So what is the C# approach to overloading unary assignment operators like I do in C++?

Because, just leaving out the first line in above static operator+ - function will change `A` in the following scenario:

```
obj C = A + B;
```

so, for pretty obvious reasons:

after `A += B`, `A` should still be the **same** object.

Of course, I can just implement it the way it should be:

```
public obj add(obj B)
{
    magic += B.magic;
    return this;
}

public static obj operator+(obj A, obj B)
{
    obj ret = new obj();
    ret.magic = A.magic;
    ret.add(B);
    return ret;
}
```

But then, it still wont get called on `A += B`, which will break expectations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to overload compound assignment operator in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869245/simple-way-to-overload-compound-assignment-operator-in-c)

Comment: The operator overloading code of yours creates a new object and sums up the values of a and b to is magic property. You should do `a.magin += b.magin; return a;` to see the changes happening in object a.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading assignment operator in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537803/overloading-assignment-operator-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public static obj operator+(obj a, obj b)
{
    a.magic += b.magic;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: that would change a in obj c = a + b;

Comment: This code worked perfectly. It modified the property of obj a with the summed up value. Did you try this code @rhavin ? Did it not give the proper value ?

Answer (score 0):

`a += b;` *is* a shortcut to `a = a + b`

So reusing the same object or creating new one is whole responsibility of `+` operator.

Technically, all "standard" implementations of `+` always create new object, but with `struct`s you just don't notice that.

You can implement your `+` logic in a way that it just returns left operand.

Comment: Well, in c++ it is not. there it is a 'modify a by b' not a 'create new anonymous, modify it by a and b and reassign to a' - which is clearly not what i need.

Comment: @rhavin This is C# question.

Comment: Yeah, thats why i'm asking how to do it in C#.

Comment: @rhavin - try to understand the answers you already have. I here and @Sty below shows you how to implement `+` in such a way it uses the provided object instead of creating new one - that's just *your* code in `+` operator.

Comment: Please try to understand the problem, not providing a solution for something different.

Answer (score -1):

You are not able to directly overload "+=" operator, you can read more at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx)

Basically, behavior depends on your "+" operator overload. (You are creating new object in that method)

Comment: Down for stating something I already know (its in the title!) and not adressing the problem at all.

Comment: @rhavin well problem is obvious, I stated it inside braces, you mustn't create new object if you want `A` to be the same object.